# JpaRepository findAll returns empty List

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, httprequest

`findAll()` method from `JpaRepository` returns empty value, but correct number of empty values

I'm using h2 database and everything has worked fine until some unknown moment. Simple GET at `http://localhost:8080/users` returns {} x number of users previously added to the database. I tried implementing a method that would return id based on username and that works just fine.

Here is my `User.java`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotBlank(message = "Username is mandatory")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20, message = "Username must be less than 20 characters long")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "balance")
    private Double balance = 0.0;

    Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    Double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    void setBalance(Double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

Here is `UserService` which implements methods from `IUserService`:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void createNewUser(User user) {
        repository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Long findByUsername(String username) {
        return repository.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean checkIfUsernameIsTaken(User user) {
        return repository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteUser(Long id) {
        repository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateBalance(Long id, Double balance) {
        repository.updateBalance(id, balance);
    }
}
```

I tried with and without `@Column` annotations and it doesn't seem to do anything.

The output I get from Postman is [{}] if I added only one user via `createNewuser()`, [{},{}] if I added two users and so on. I don't understand what broke the `findAll()` method.

P.S. `updateBalance()` doesn't work either, but that's for some other time.

Edit: some ov you asked for `UserController`:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public List<User> findUsers() {
        return userService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User findUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return userService.findById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {

        if (userService.checkIfUsernameIsTaken(user)) {

            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("status", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
            response.put("errors", "Username is already taken");
            response.put("timestamp", new Date());

            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        } else {
            userService.createNewUser(user);
            User currentUser = userService.findById(userService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()));
            Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
            response.put("id", currentUser.getId());
            response.put("username", currentUser.getUsername());
            response.put("balance", currentUser.getBalance());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/users/{id}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        userService.deleteUser(id);
    }

    @PutMapping("/users/{id}/{balance}")
    public void updateBalance(@PathVariable Long id, @PathVariable Double balance) {
        userService.updateBalance(id, balance);
    }
}
```

and `UserRepository`:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT id FROM User WHERE username = ?1")
    Long findByUsername(String username);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE User SET balance = ?2 WHERE id = ?1")
    void updateBalance(Long id, Double balance);
}
```

My problems first appeared (or so I think) after I implmented the update query, but I tried running a version where I know it worked on a different computer, but it didn't work.

Comment: how did you implement your `UserRepository`? can you add code for that class as well.

Comment: @AmitNaik Spring Data provides the implementation automatically.

Comment: Filip, this is a side issue, but you have a number of style issues that should be corrected. Avoid using `optional.get()`; your entire method can be replaced with `return repository.findById(id).getOrElse(null);`. Similarly, it is considered generally noisy and unhelpful to perform explicit null checks if you're going to throw exceptions anyway; if you really want to, use `Objects.requireNonNull(user.getUsername())`.

Comment: @chrylis I know hoping there no implementation added for `findAll`. Just to clear it and not having any assumption here

Comment: Can you provide your complete Controller and Repository code snippet ?

Comment: are you using your repository code like `UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>`  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your properties are not *mutable*. You have exposed getters and setters but you didn't specify access level, and they are not *public* by default, so hibernate can not see them and hence can not populate your entity with the record returned from the database. Making them *public* should resolve the issue.

Comment: Hibernate as well as HttpMessageConverters cannot see the properties that's why `{ }` is returned, Otherwise `{ "id" : null , "username" : null}` would have returned.

So making Getters and Setters `public` in the entity class should solve this issue

Comment: of-course, you mentioned Hibernate , I just added the reason for empty json object too

Comment: Thank you! The IDE(IntelliJ Idea) suggested that getters and setters could be package-private so I made them package-private.

Comment: Often, IntelliJ, tries to be smarter than it actually is :)

Comment: Thanks. In the Entity class , i changed `private int id;` to `public int id;` and now i am getting desired response.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer above fixes the issue, I have encountered a similar situation where `repository.findById(id)` would return a result and `repository.findAll()` would return empty.

It turns out that I had wrapped the caller method with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`, where the method would write and then read all records:

```
@Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Object> writeThenReadAll(...){
       repository.save(...);
       ...
       Object byId = repository.findById(1L).get(); //not null
       List<Object> all = repository.findAll(); //returns empty
       return all;
    }
```

changing `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` to `@Transactional(readOnly = false)` fixed the issue.